# Is WSL2 installation mandatory for bringing up formsflow.ai in Docker?

Tags: docker-compose, wsl-2, formsflow.ai

I'm been reading about [formsflow.ai](https://github.com/AOT-Technologies/forms-flow-ai). So I was interested in the project and decided to bring it up on my system.

The first step in the installation guide is docker-compose, but when I tried to install Docker in my Windows system it shows that WSL2 is necessary.  As part of the installation, it redirected to https://wslstorestorage.blob.core.windows.net/wslblob/wsl_update_x64.msi.

Is it necessary to complete the six steps in the above link? Or is Linux is mandatory for this?

Comment: This looks like you are trying to reach the maintainers of the code. Please review their site for possible instructions, we are not they, and can't really help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a quick scan of the formsflow.ai installation instructions, the only supported installation methods are Docker or OpenShift.  Only the Docker option would be viable on Windows.

And yes, WSL2 is the preferred method of installing Docker Desktop.  As an alternative, you can use the older Hyper-V method, but I would highly recommend WSL2 if you are going to be going this route.

I haven't tried this (since I already have WSL2 installed), but I see in the [Docker Desktop installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) that there is an option in the installer to *"Install required Windows components for WSL 2"*.  That appears to be what you are doing.

There's also the option to [install WSL2 components manually](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10#manual-installation-steps).  Please note that the "Simplified install" mentioned at the top of that page is only an option with Windows 10 Preview on the Insiders program.